# swap the values of 4 variables with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Originally I was using the following to swap the values of 2 variables at random when the page loaded:

```
    var value1 = 260;
    var value2 = 325;
    var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? value1 : value2;
    if (value1 == chosenValue) { var val = value1; } else { var val = value2; }
    if (value1 == chosenValue) { var val2 = value2; } else { var val2 = value1; }
```

However now I need to swap out 4 values and I no idea how to go about doing that.

```
    var value1 = 260;
    var value2 = 325;
    var value3 = 195;
    var value4 = 130;
```

Note that each value must be used only once and must be displayed in random order each time page is loaded.

help?

Comment: Why do you have same if condition twice?

Comment: I honestly don't have an answer.... I obviously should have just used an and on the first statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

Creating an array (`arrayValues`) with all the values (using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)), we use `splice` to remove a random value and, since `splice` modifies the source array, no value is repeated.

```js
var value1 = 260;
var value2 = 325;
var value3 = 195;
var value4 = 130;

var arrayValues = [].concat(value1, value2, value3, value4);

value1 = arrayValues.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayValues.length), 1);
value2 = arrayValues.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayValues.length), 1);
value3 = arrayValues.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayValues.length), 1);
value4 = arrayValues.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayValues.length), 1);

console.log("value1: " + value1 + ", value2: "+ value2+ ", value3: " + value3 + ", value 4: " + value4)
```

Comment: Thank you, I voted you up and marked you correct because you gave working example AND explained it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all values to array, shuffle it ([How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)) and then simple write
value1 = arr[0]
value2 = arr[1] etc..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var randomValues = [260, 325, 195, 130].sort(function() {
    return .5 - Math.random();
});

// Array with the new random values
console.log(randomValues);
```